# How to upload file on server disc to S3 with Shrine and make it public?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

I want to upload file located on disk to S3 and make it public.

```
obj.file_attacher.assign(File.open(processed_file, binmode: true), upload_options: { acl: "public-read" })
```

Upload works but file is not public. `obj.file_url` returns:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_ifle.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAWI2QZS65O5D6QAHF%2F20190624%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-D
```

I want that `obj.file_url` would return plain URL-s (no signatures etc ..):

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_ifle.mp3
```